# Programa Crashea de la nada C++

Tags: c++

tengo un problema con un software desarrollado en C++, estuve muchas cosas y al estar ejecutandose durante 2 o 3 horas el programa produce error y se cierra, el error que me muestra es el siguiente pero no logro entender que es...

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc)

> #### std::bad_alloc
>
> `std::bad_alloc` is the type of the object thrown as exceptions by the allocation functions to report failure to allocate storage.

Lo cual, en traducción libre y resumida, viene a decir que **tu programa se ha quedado sin memoria**.

Esta excepción es lanzada tanto por `operator new` como por `operator new[]` cuando no puede satisfacer la petición.

No es 100% seguro, puesto que puede ser lanzada mediante `thrown` en cualquier parte del código.

La solución real pasa por examinar tu programa: suele indicar que estás dejando trozos de memoria sin liberar (llamando a `delete` o `delete[]`). También puede darse de forma *normal*, porque estés trabajando con tal cantidad de datos que el sistema sea incapaz de satisfacer tus demandas.

Además, ten en cuenta que también puede producirse aunque no seas tú el que la lanza (alguna librería en C++ que estés usando), o porque el verdadero culpable sea un trozo de código en C que no realice las adecuadas llamadas a `free( )`. Aunque esto no lanzará la excepción (C no tiene excepciones), puede usar tantos recursos que llamadas posteriores a `new` en tu código fallen y generen la excepción.

Lo que se sele hacer en estos casos: empieza a revisar con detenimiento tus lógicas de llamadas a `new` y `delete` :-)

Comment: Muchas Gracias... me habia quedado pensando porque en este tipo de aplicaciones nose utilizan los llamados delete o new.... pero unos dias atras habia copiado unas funciones de otro software y estaba la llamada delete, la borre y quedo todo bien, muchas gracias